# Import curses presents an error

Tags: python, colors, curses

I've searched for hours but can't find anything that works so I figured I'd just ask directly. I've been trying to use curses but whatever I do it doesn't work. My code is-

```
import curses

from curses.wrapper import wrapper


def main(scr):
    scr.box()
    scr.refresh()
    c = scr.getch()


wrapper(main)
```

But the error I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Desktop/Code/Code.py", line 3, in <module>
    from curses.wrapper import wrapper
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'curses.wrapper'
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Another problem I have is that if I try to use 'from curses import wrapper', the shell can't find the terminal

Answer (score 0):

The `import` doesn't work since you're attempting to treat the `wrapper` function as a class.  This works:

```
import curses

# from curses.wrapper import wrapper

def main(scr):
    scr.box()
    scr.refresh()
    c = scr.getch()

curses.wrapper(main)
```

and so does this:

```
import curses

from curses import wrapper

def main(scr):
    scr.box()
    scr.refresh()
    c = scr.getch()

wrapper(main)
```